# Java- ассемблер, выдает ошибку в jvm

Tags: java, ассемблер, jni

Мне необходимо каким-то образом сделать небольшую вставку в java на asm
Пытался сделать по единственному гайду в русскоязычном интернете-не сработало(использовался jni)
Сам гайд-[Java/asm](https://habr.com/ru/company/jugru/blog/347200)
Код хоть компилируется и запускается(значения в регистрах меняется), но всё равно выдает ошибку
Причем,ошибку выдает именно в jvm.dll(если верить логам),а если ломать asm код,то выдасть в созданной мною dll
Нужна помощь тех,кто пытался делать что-то подобное

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JNIMethod jniArraySum = new JNIMethod();
        int[] input = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

        System.out.println(jniArraySum.computeNativeArraySum(input, input.length));
    }}



public class JNIMethod {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("ArraySum");
    }
    public native long computeNativeArraySum(int[] array, int arrayLength);}




 global Java_JNIMethod_computeNativeArraySum
 section .data
    ; JNI function indexes can be found in the following documentation:
    ; http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html
    GetIntArrayElements:        equ 187*8
    ReleaseIntArrayElements:    equ 195*8
 section .text
 Java_JNIMethod_computeNativeArraySum:
        push rdx        ; store Java array pointer
        push rdi        ; store JNIEnv pointer
        push rcx        ; store array length
        mov rsi, rdx        ; set array parameter for GetIntArrayElements
        mov rax, [rdi]      ; get location of JNI function table
        xor edx, edx        ; set isCopy to false
        call [rax + GetIntArrayElements]
        pop rcx         ; retrieve array length
        lea rcx, [rax + 4 * rcx]; compute address following last array element
        mov r8, rax     ; copy native array pointer
        xor ebx, ebx        ; sum variable
        add_element:
            movsx r9, dword [rax]   ; get current element
            add rbx, r9     ; add next element
            add rax, 4      ; move array pointer to next element
            cmp rax, rcx        ; check whether all array was processed
            jne add_element
        pop rdi         ; retrieve JNIEnv
        pop rsi         ; retrieve Java array pointer
        push rbx        ; store sum result
        mov rax, [rdi]      ; get location of JNI function table
        mov rdx, r8     ; set elems parameter for ReleaseIntArrayElements
        call [rax + ReleaseIntArrayElements]
        pop rax         ; retrieve sum result
        ret
```

Текст ошибки

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000600d8bdf, pid=7588, tid=0x0000000000002f54
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_301-b09) (build 1.8.0_301-b09)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.301-b09 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x68bdf]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000253d3642800):  VMThread [stack: 0x000000dc46100000,0x000000dc46200000] [id=12116]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000010

Registers:
RAX=0x00000253b8501119, RBX=0x000000dc45cff410, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000000051
RSP=0x000000dc461ff910, RBP=0x000000000000000c, RSI=0x0000000000000010, RDI=0x00000253b83b5b70
R8 =0xffffffffffffffff, R9 =0x8101010101010100, R10=0x810100f8f8fef0fe, R11=0x00000253b8501119
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00000253d2eb5500, R14=0x00000253d2eb58d8, R15=0x00000000000003d8
RIP=0x00000000600d8bdf, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000dc461ff910)
0x000000dc461ff910:   0000000000000000 00000253b83b59f0
0x000000dc461ff920:   0000000000000100 0000000000000000
0x000000dc461ff930:   00000253b83b5b70 00000000602f92f9
0x000000dc461ff940:   000000dc45cff410 0000000000000010
0x000000dc461ff950:   00000253d36425e0 0000000060300768
0x000000dc461ff960:   000000dc461ffa00 00000253d36425e0
0x000000dc461ff970:   00000253d2eb5500 00000000602b5b57
0x000000dc461ff980:   0000000000000000 000000dc45cff410
0x000000dc461ff990:   00000253d2eb54f0 0000000060270100
0x000000dc461ff9a0:   00000253d2eb54f0 0000000000000000
0x000000dc461ff9b0:   00000253d36425e0 00000000602b42c5
0x000000dc461ff9c0:   00000253b83b6000 0000000000000000
0x000000dc461ff9d0:   000000dc45cff410 00000000607f93c0
0x000000dc461ff9e0:   0000000060614000 0000000000000000
0x000000dc461ff9f0:   0000000000000000 000000dc461ffa80
0x000000dc461ffa00:   0000000000000000 00000000000fbb82 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000600d8bdf)
0x00000000600d8bbf:   48 8b 7c 24 78 48 83 c4 40 41 5f 41 5e 41 5c c3
0x00000000600d8bcf:   cc 48 89 5c 24 08 48 89 74 24 10 57 48 83 ec 20
0x00000000600d8bdf:   48 8b 79 10 48 8b f1 48 85 ff 0f 85 52 01 00 00
0x00000000600d8bef:   48 8b 59 18 48 85 db 74 0c 48 8b cb e8 60 57 1a 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00000253b8501119 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000dc45cff410 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000253b83b8000
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000051 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000dc461ff910 is an unknown value
RBP=0x000000000000000c is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000253b83b5b70 is an unknown value
R8 =0xffffffffffffffff is an unknown value
R9 =0x8101010101010100 is an unknown value
R10=0x810100f8f8fef0fe is an unknown value
R11=0x00000253b8501119 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x00000253d2eb5500 is an unknown value
R14=0x00000253d2eb58d8 is an unknown value
R15=0x00000000000003d8 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x000000dc46100000,0x000000dc46200000],  sp=0x000000dc461ff910,  free space=1022k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x68bdf]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2892f9]
V  [jvm.dll+0x245b57]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2442c5]
V  [jvm.dll+0x244a3c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x244d4c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x2923dc]
C  [ucrtbase.dll+0x21bb2]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x17034]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x52651]

VM_Operation (0x000000dc45cff410): CollectForMetadataAllocation, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x00000253b83b8000


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000253d4280800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9672, stack(0x000000dc46a00000,0x000000dc46b00000)]
  0x00000253d3733800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11572, stack(0x000000dc46900000,0x000000dc46a00000)]
  0x00000253d372a000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6124, stack(0x000000dc46800000,0x000000dc46900000)]
  0x00000253d3727000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4916, stack(0x000000dc46700000,0x000000dc46800000)]
  0x00000253d36dc000 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=11768, stack(0x000000dc46600000,0x000000dc46700000)]
  0x00000253d3690800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6148, stack(0x000000dc46500000,0x000000dc46600000)]
  0x00000253d368e000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11292, stack(0x000000dc46400000,0x000000dc46500000)]
  0x00000253d2f3b800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11764, stack(0x000000dc46300000,0x000000dc46400000)]
  0x00000253d3666000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11308, stack(0x000000dc46200000,0x000000dc46300000)]
  0x00000253b83b8000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=7508, stack(0x000000dc45c00000,0x000000dc45d00000)]

Other Threads:
=>0x00000253d3642800 VMThread [stack: 0x000000dc46100000,0x000000dc46200000] [id=12116]
  0x00000253d429e000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000dc46b00000,0x000000dc46c00000] [id=11592]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00000253b83b6d70] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x00000253d3642800
[0x00000253b83b68f0] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x00000253b83b8000

heap address: 0x00000006c1000000, size: 4080 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x00000007c0000000

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 3932K [0x000000076b000000, 0x0000000770500000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65536K, 6% used [0x000000076b000000,0x000000076b3d70e0,0x000000076f000000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076fa80000,0x000000076fa80000,0x0000000770500000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076f000000,0x000000076f000000,0x000000076fa80000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 0K [0x00000006c1000000, 0x00000006cbb00000, 0x000000076b000000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c1000000,0x00000006c1000000,0x00000006cbb00000)
 Metaspace       used 3203K, capacity 4500K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 353K, capacity 388K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x00000253c9170000,0x00000253c9970000] byte_map_base: 0x00000253c5b68000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000060857fe0
 Begin Bits: [0x00000253c9ec0000, 0x00000253cde80000)
 End Bits:   [0x00000253cde80000, 0x00000253d1e40000)

Polling page: 0x00000253b84e0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=1136Kb max_used=1146Kb free=244623Kb
 bounds [0x00000253b9db0000, 0x00000253ba020000, 0x00000253c8db0000]
 total_blobs=289 nmethods=36 adapters=168
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.101 Thread 0x00000253d3733800 nmethod 31 0x00000253b9ec8bd0 code [0x00000253b9ec8de0, 0x00000253b9ec9920]
Event: 0.101 Thread 0x00000253d3733800   32       3       java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::append (50 bytes)
Event: 0.101 Thread 0x00000253d3733800 nmethod 32 0x00000253b9ec9e50 code [0x00000253b9eca020, 0x00000253b9eca780]
Event: 0.101 Thread 0x00000253d3733800   33       1       java.util.ArrayList::size (5 bytes)
Event: 0.101 Thread 0x00000253d3733800 nmethod 33 0x00000253b9ecaa90 code [0x00000253b9ecabe0, 0x00000253b9ecacf8]
Event: 0.102 Thread 0x00000253d3733800   34       3       java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap::tabAt (21 bytes)
Event: 0.102 Thread 0x00000253d3733800 nmethod 34 0x00000253b9ecc650 code [0x00000253b9ecc7a0, 0x00000253b9ecc9d8]
Event: 0.102 Thread 0x00000253d3727000 nmethod 28 0x00000253b9ece490 code [0x00000253b9ece5e0, 0x00000253b9ece908]
Event: 0.103 Thread 0x00000253d3733800   36       3       sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder::encode (32 bytes)
Event: 0.103 Thread 0x00000253d3733800 nmethod 36 0x00000253b9ecbf90 code [0x00000253b9ecc100, 0x00000253b9ecc318]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (2 events):
Event: 0.027 Thread 0x00000253b83b8000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x000000076b007cc0) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u301\1513\hot
Event: 0.027 Thread 0x00000253b83b8000 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x000000076b007fa8) thrown at [C:\jenkins\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u301\1513\hotspot\src\share\vm\

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.101 loading class sun/net/NetHooks done
Event: 0.102 loading class java/net/Socket$2
Event: 0.102 loading class java/net/Socket$2 done
Event: 0.102 loading class java/net/SocketInputStream
Event: 0.102 loading class java/net/SocketInputStream done
Event: 0.102 loading class sun/nio/cs/US_ASCII$Decoder
Event: 0.102 loading class java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper
Event: 0.102 loading class sun/nio/cs/US_ASCII$Decoder done
Event: 0.102 loading class java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper done
Event: 0.103 Executing VM operation: CollectForMetadataAllocation


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff623240000 - 0x00007ff623287000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe
0x00007ffff1810000 - 0x00007ffff1a05000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007fffefbe0000 - 0x00007fffefc9e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007fffef5a0000 - 0x00007fffef868000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffff0d90000 - 0x00007ffff0e3e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffff0580000 - 0x00007ffff061e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffff15f0000 - 0x00007ffff168c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffff0c30000 - 0x00007ffff0d55000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffff0e40000 - 0x00007ffff0fe0000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007fffef120000 - 0x00007fffef142000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffff06f0000 - 0x00007ffff071b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007fffef330000 - 0x00007fffef43b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007fffef290000 - 0x00007fffef32d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007fffef020000 - 0x00007fffef120000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007fffe3db0000 - 0x00007fffe404a000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.1110_none_60b5254171f9507e\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffff0d60000 - 0x00007ffff0d90000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007fffea470000 - 0x00007fffea485000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\bin\vcruntime140.dll
0x00007fffdcbc0000 - 0x00007fffdcc5b000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\bin\msvcp140.dll
0x0000000060070000 - 0x00000000608d0000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007fffefbd0000 - 0x00007fffefbd8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007fffe5dd0000 - 0x00007fffe5dd9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffff1580000 - 0x00007ffff15eb000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007fffe9790000 - 0x00007fffe979a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007fffe3610000 - 0x00007fffe3637000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007fffecef0000 - 0x00007fffecf02000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007fffeaa00000 - 0x00007fffeaa10000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00007fffe5e10000 - 0x00007fffe5e3b000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\bin\java.dll
0x00007fffe5cc0000 - 0x00007fffe5cf0000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\bin\instrument.dll
0x00007fffe5db0000 - 0x00007fffe5dc8000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007fffefcb0000 - 0x00007ffff03f4000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007fffed060000 - 0x00007fffed7f4000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007fffef870000 - 0x00007fffefbc4000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007fffee920000 - 0x00007fffee94c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Wldp.dll
0x00007ffff14b0000 - 0x00007ffff155d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHCORE.dll
0x00007ffff0400000 - 0x00007ffff0455000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007fffeee70000 - 0x00007fffeee8f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x00007fffe5d90000 - 0x00007fffe5daa000     C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2021.1.3\bin\breakgen64.dll
0x00007fffdd360000 - 0x00007fffdd37c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007fffee620000 - 0x00007fffee68a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007fffdd1b0000 - 0x00007fffdd1c3000     C:\Users\Ramil\IdeaProjects\JNITest\src\ArraySum.dll
0x00007fffe2b20000 - 0x00007fffe2d04000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll
0x00007fffef150000 - 0x00007fffef1d2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Ramil\IdeaProjects\JNITest\src -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2021.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=23277:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2021.1.3\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: Main
java_class_path (initial): C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Ramil\IdeaProjects\JNITest\out\production\JNITest;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2021.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301
PATH=c:\minigw\bin;c:\minigw\libexec\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\11.2.0;C:\Users\Ramil\gcc\bin;C:\Users\Ramil\gcc\libexec\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\11.2.0;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\Ramil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\Ramil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\Ramil\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition 2021.1.3\bin;C:\Users\Ramil\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Ramil\AppData\Local\atom\bin
USERNAME=Ramil
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 23 Model 8 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 19041 (10.0.19041.1566)

CPU:total 4 (initial active 4) (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 23 model 8 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, mmxext, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, sse4a, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv, bmi1

Memory: 4k page, physical 16707512k(10104196k free), swap 19197880k(9940776k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.301-b09) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_301-b09), built on Jun  9 2021 06:46:21 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 15.9 (VS2017)

time: Sun Apr 10 21:57:22 2022
timezone: RTZ 2 (зима)
elapsed time: 0.117849 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

Comment: mail.ru - сайт не существует. Пользуйтесь нормальными сайтами.

Comment: Совет,конечно хороший.Но кроме маила и яндекса я ничего не знаю.Скажите на какой,я загружу

Comment: Это не java ассемблер, а обычная C JNI dll, написанная на ассемблере, причем непонятно зачем, ведь то же самое можно было бы сделать и на С/C++. А ошибку следует приводить текстом в самом вопросе.

Comment: По тз необходимо, хотя через С было бы намного легче.Но нужно именно асм

Comment: я бы сделал вначале на си, убедился, что оно работает, а потом пробовал бы переписывать на асм.

Comment: Попробую так сделать,отпишусь